# eBay API PHP SDK getting cURL error 60: SSL certificate

Tags: php, curl, wamp, guzzle, ebay-api

I am using eBay API PHP SDK and get this error when running on my local WAMP server in Win 7:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in C:\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 187
>   ( ! ) GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in C:\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 187

Image:

[image: error pic]

Comment: Did you follow the explanatory link in the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Ebay SDK SSL certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932335/php-ebay-sdk-ssl-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check certificate and system CURL version. I had the same problem on my machine and updating CURL lib helped (because I'm using macports it was easy:

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port upgrade curl
```

If You are using different platform or package manager You need to investigate

Answer (score 0):

you have to set in php.ini and restart server.

```
openssl.cafile=C:\path\to\cacert.pem
```

download it from here
https://gist.github.com/VersatilityWerks/5719158/download

Comment: Doesn't this need to be done every few months, so this file doesn't become outdated?